# Tell pylint that a given decorator is a classmethod

Tags: python, pylint, class-method, pylintrc

How can I modify my pylintrc so that a given decorator is interpreted as a classmethod.

`pydantic` defines a `validator` decorator to allow for attribute validation of model classes and operates as a class method.  `pylint` throws a

```
E0213: Method 'has_risk_assigned' should have "self" as first argument (no-self-argument)
```

for a validator method declared as:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class RiskyRecord(BaseModel):
    # ... attributes ...

    @validator('risk')
    def has_risk_assigned(cls, v):
          # ... make sure that risk is properly assigned ...
```

How can I configure my pylintrc such that it views this decorator as defining a class (instead of instance) method?

Note: I want a solution in terms of pylintrc since there are multiple classes in this module that each use multiple validators; managing this warning in one place is more desirable.

I only see two classmethod related features in my current pylintrc; both only relate to the valid name(s) for the first argument.

Comment: I think this is a case where `pylint` needs a plugin to learn that `pydantic.validator(...)` returns a class method.

Answer (score 3):

Chepner said it correctly, in the comments; a plugin is necessary for `Pylint` to understand that `pydantic.validator` returns a class method.

Such a plugin exists in the form of [pylint-pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-pydantic/) and it works to prevent the `no-self-argument` message from being emitted when the `pydantic.validator` decorator is used.

It can be added to a `pylintrc` like so:

```
load-plugins = pylint_pydantic
```

Alternatively, using `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pylint]
load-plugins = "pylint_pydantic"
```

For further reading about Pylint plugins, there is a short list available available in the [Pylint documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html#how-to-use-pylint).